# Nap6.4 for tcl fails to install and make due to "conflicted types for Nap_parse"

Tags: tcl, bison

I need to install Nap6.4, but it fails with an "error: conflicting types for Nap_parse". I have a Dockerfile where I include "ADD ./nap6_4_0src.tar.gz /usr/local" and from usr/local/nap/unix I type:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local && make && make install
```

I have installed Proj4, hdf4 and netcdf using the same approach. I have also tried other versions of Nap, but they all give the same error. I have spent the last days trying to modify the files under nap/generic, some of them are generated by Bison and there is also some m4 files there. Does anyone recognize this error and know how to fix it? Any help will be highly appreciated!

Here is the error message:

```
cc -c -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"\" -   DPACKAGE_STRING=\"\" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"\" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -DUSE_TCL_STUBS=1 -DUSE_TK_STUBS=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -DISNAN64=isnan -DVERSION=\"6.4\" -DPATCHLEVEL=\".0\" -I`echo /build/nap/generic` -I`echo /usr/local/include` -I`echo /usr/local/include` -I`echo /usr/local/include` -I`echo /lib/ActiveTcl-8.6/include` -O -D__NO_STRING_INLINES -D__NO_MATH_INLINES  -fPIC  `echo /build/nap/generic/eval_tree.c`
In file included from /build/nap/generic/eval_tree.c:16:0:
/build/nap/generic/napParse.tab.h:79:5: error: conflicting types for 'Nap_parse'
int Nap_parse (void);
 ^
In file included from /build/nap/generic/eval_tree.c:14:0:
   /build/nap/generic/nap.h,m4:610:13: note: previous declaration of Nap_parse was here
EXTERN int  Nap_parse(void *Nap_param); /* Defined in napParse.y */
         ^
make: *** [eval_tree.o] Error 1
```

Additionally, I get some other errors:

```
napParse.tab.c:2122:46: error: macro "Nap_error" passed 2 arguments, but     takes just 1
/usr/local/nap/generic/napParse.tab.c:65:25: error: 'Nap_error' undeclared  (first use in this function)
 #define yyerror         Nap_error
                     ^
napParse.tab.c:2122:7: note: in expansion of macro 'yyerror'
/usr/local/nap/generic/napParse.tab.c:65:25: note: each undeclared identifier  is reported only once for each function it appears in
 #define yyerror         Nap_error
                     ^
```

and

```
 make: *** No rule to make target `netcdf.h', needed by `nap_get.o'.
```

I suspect the latter one along with some other similar errors are because I tried

```
./configure --prefix=/lib/ActiveTcl8.6
```

Any ideas of what goes wrong here?

Comment: Is the nap build process recreating napParse.tab.c and napParse.tab.h (check their creation dates)? And, if so, what version of yacc/ bison do you have installed?

Answer (score 1):

The source code for Nap6.4 is very old, and it seems to expect a particular range of versions of bison. It's likely that your bison is too new to fit into this range.

In particular, lines 28 and 29 of [`napParse.y`](http://tcl-nap.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/tcl-nap/tcl-nap/generic/napParse.y?revision=1.69&view=markup):

```
#define YYPARSE_PARAM Nap_param
#define YYLEX_PARAM Nap_param
```

will not have any effect if your bison is v2.7 or more recent. Those macros were already deprecated in 2002, and in 2012 they were actually removed from the generated code. So the `define`s will have no effect.

Also, in line 36:

```
%pure_parser
```

I think this may still be accepted but it has been deprecated for a good long time, too.

With a modern bison, you would want to delete those three lines, and then (where the `%pure_parser` declaration used to be), insert the following:

```
%define api.pure full
%param { void* Nap_param }
```

If your version of bison is not quite so up-to-date, it might complain about the `%param` line, in which case you could use:

```
%define api.pure full
%parse-param { void* Nap_param }
%lex-param { void* Nap_param }
```

You will also need to correct the definition of `Nap_error`, which you will find in the file `generic/nap_check.h` at line 194. That definition should read:

```
#define Nap_error(Nap_param, message) \
    Nap_Check(Nap_param, __FILE__, __LINE__, message)
```

Current `bison` scanners add the parameter specified in `%parse-param` to the call to the error function, so you need to change the prototype of the macro to accept the parameter rather than picking it up from the environment.

If that works, you might want to file a bug report, although it is not at all clear to me that anyone is maintaining that software.

Comment: I found out that my Bison version is 3.0.2, so I removed the lines you suggested and replaced %pure_parser as you said. This seems to have worked for this problem. However, now I get: napParse.tab.c: In function 'Nap_parse':
napParse.tab.c:2147:35: error: macro "Nap_error" passed 2 arguments, but takes just 1
/usr/local/nap/generic/napParse.tab.c:65:25: error: 'Nap_error' undeclared (first use in this function). Do I need to change the line "#define yyerror  Nap_error" as well?

Comment: @Kristin: Sorry, I missed one change because I misunderstood the legacy provisions of `api.pure`. I'll fix the answer.

Comment: @KristinSolbakken: I tested it that change and built `napParse.tab.o` without errors. So as far as the bison issues go, I *think* that will do it. Of course, I can't vouch for its execution.

Comment: Thanks, I thin this solved those issues. Of course the make still doesn't work, due to "relocation R_X86_64_32 against '.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC".. Ever come across this error message before?

Comment: @Kristin: Nope, but the message seems to indicate that there is a statically-compiled library which the Makefile is trying to incorporate into a shared object. You'll have to at least identify what was being done which generated that error, and then you could put all the details into another question. I don't think it's related to the bison issues.

Comment: Thnx anyways for helping out with the napParse.y file :)